# Performing basic image processing over multiple images

Tags: r, for-loop, image-processing

I want to perform basic image pre-processing on drone images (.jpeg). Per drone mission (consisting of about 250 images), I want to add a single image, transform to grayscale, calculate the variance in pixels values of the grayscaled image, then save the jpeg file name with associated variance in a new data.frame. I can do this per image, but I would like to automate this by using a for loop. Other words, I would like a for loop that loads a single image, transforms to grayscale, calculates variance, and saves the results, then repeats this for the next image in the folder directory.

I am using the imager R package for all my coding.

```
library(imager)

#directory containing images of a drone mission

    setwd("D:..../R/Drone_Pilot_Study") 

#loading single image

    img<-load.image("D:..../R/Drone_Pilot_Study/0001.jpg")

#transforming to grayscale

    imgGray<-grayscale(img, method="Luma", drop=TRUE)

#calculating variance

     var<-var(imgGray)
```

Can anyone help advice on how to incorporate this code into a for loop and then to save the results in a data.frame?

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an follow up on @Hayden Y. answer. I managed to get it to work. Here is my code.

```
#Load libraries
library(imager)
library(magick)

#Set working directory
setwd("D:/..../R/Drone_Pilot_Study/")

#Object containing images
image.files <- dir("D:/..../R/Drone_Pilot_Study/Images/",full.names = TRUE)

#Create a list to store outputs
output<-vector("list", length(image.files))

#Run the following operation for each element in image.files
for(i in seq_along(image.files)){
  img<-load.image(image.files[i])
  sd<-sd(img)
  imgGray<-grayscale(img, method="Luma", drop=TRUE)
  var<-var(imgGray)
  output[[i]]<-c(image.files[i],sd, var)
}

#Convert output to dataframe
results<-as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", output)) 

#Renaming column names
names(results)[1]<-"dir"
names(results)[2]<-"sd"
names(results)[3]<-"var"
```

Specifying the file directory within the loop was causing issues. But this works fine.

Thanks Hayden.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following be what you're looking for?

```
dir<-"D:..../R/Drone_Pilot_Study/" # Set directory
image.files<-list.files(dir) # List all files in the directory
output<-vec("list", length(image.files)) # Create a list to store outputs
for(i in seq_along(image.files)){ # Run the following operation for each element in image.files
    img<-load.image(paste0(dir, image.files[i]))
    imgGray<-grayscale(img, method="Luma", drop=TRUE)
    var<-var(imgGray)
    output[[i]]<-c(image.files[i], var)
}
dataframe<-do.call("rbind", output) # Convert output to dataframe
```

In the code above, I've assumed that you want to run this on all files in the given directory, and that there are no non-image files in the directory. If this is not the case, you can do something like `image.files<-list.files(dir, pattern="*.jpg")` so as to only include files with the .jpg extension.

Comment: Thanks so much Hayden. When running the loop I get the following error:  "Error in wrap.url(file, load.image.internal) : File not found". I will try using Magick to read in the images and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The problem might be that `dir` doesn't have a "/" at the end. I've updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: The / did not make a difference, same error. When using Magick functions I get this error: "Error in magick_image_readpath(enc2native(path), density, depth, strip) : 
  Magick: UnableToOpenBlob `D:....\R\Drone_Pilot_Study\Images\ D:\.....\R\Drone_Pilot_Study\Images\DJI_0001.JPG': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701".

Comment: That sounds like there's something wrong with the file path, or possibly the file itself, but unfortunately that's not a problem I can reproduce.

Comment: Yes might be the file directory. Will remove all spaces and also try a different directory. Thanks for your help Hayden.